# Erro ao cadastrar no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro pelo `form` do sistema, porém estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem :

**Erro**:

```
  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
  (`gpiweb_pdi`.`avaliacoes_simulados`, CONSTRAINT
  `fk_usuario_cadastro_avaliacoes_simulados` FOREIGN KEY
  (`usuario_cadastro`) REFERENCES `usuarios_acesso` (`id_usuario`) ON
 DELETE NO ACTION ON U)
```

Alguém saberia o que pode ser e como resolver?

Obrigado

Comment: como é que vc tá fazendo essa transação ? é insert? update? delete?

Comment: pelo que vi tá faltando vc setar o id_usuário para funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito José Vieira...é exatamente isso... não podia ir vazio esse campo... Obrigado

Comment: O erro tem haver com a chave estrangeira FK...
Verifique na construcao da tabela se é nula... Espero ter ajudado....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica se você está `setando` o **id do usuário** na hora da sua **transação**. ele tá reclamando que a **fk** de usuário não pode ser **nula**.